# java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<ON> but was:<com.spacestudy.model.Account@783f5f71>

Tags: unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, junit4, querydsl

I am trying to write a JUnit test case for the following search filter method. I am using `Querydsl` for the search filter. The following method does not depend on Repository; that is why I am not using mockito. This is the first time I am writing a test case for such a method. Please give any suggestions, if you have any?

```
public List<Tuple> btnSearchClick(String sClientAcctId, String sAcctDesc, String sInvestigatorName,
            String sClientDeptId) throws Exception {

        QAccount account = QAccount.account;
        QDepartment department = QDepartment.department;
        QAccountCPCMapping accountCPCMapping = QAccountCPCMapping.accountCPCMapping;
        QInvestigator investigator = QInvestigator.investigator;

        JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);
        query.select(Projections.bean(Account.class, account.sClientAcctId, account.sAcctDesc, account.sLocation,
                Projections.bean(Department.class, department.sDeptName, department.sClientDeptId).as("department"),
                Projections.bean(Investigator.class, investigator.sInvestigatorName).as("investigator"),
                Projections.bean(AccountCPCMapping.class, accountCPCMapping.sCCPCode).as("accountCPC"))).from(account)
                .innerJoin(account.department, department).innerJoin(account.accountCPC, accountCPCMapping)
                .innerJoin(account.investigator, investigator).where(account.nInstId.eq(60));
```

**Test case**

```
@Test
public void btnSearchClick() throws Exception {

List<Tuple> account= accountService.btnSearchClick("1124100", sAcctDesc, sInvestigatorName, sClientDeptId);


Department dep = new Department();
dep.setsDeptName("Deans Office");
dep.setsClientDeptId("120010");

Investigator invest = new Investigator();
invest.setsInvestigatorName("Ram, Sri");

AccountCPCMapping cpc = new  AccountCPCMapping();
cpc.setsCCPCode("RT");


Account acc = new Account();
acc.setsLocation("ON");
acc.setsAcctDesc("SRIRAM");
acc.setsClientAcctId("1124100");

acc.setInvestigator(invest);
acc.setDepartment(dep);
acc.setAccountCPC(cpc); 

accountRepo.save(acc);

assertEquals(acc.getsLocation(), account.get(0));
}
```

Account.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_seq_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "account_seq_generator", sequenceName = "account_seq")

    @Column(name = "naccount_id")
    public Integer nAccountId;

    @Column(name = "namount")
    public String nAmount;

    @Column(name = "sacct_desc")
    public String sAcctDesc;

    @Column(name = "naccount_cpc_mapping_id")
    public Integer nAccountCPCMappingId;

    @Column(name = "nindirect_cost_rate")
    public Integer nIndiretCostRate;

    @Column(name = "nagency_id")
    public Integer nAgencyId;

    @Column(name = "ndept_id")
    public Integer nDeptId;

    @Column(name = "sgrant_num")
    public String sGrantNum;

    @Column(name = "dstart_date")
    public Timestamp dStartDate;

    @Column(name = "dend_date")
    public Timestamp dEndDate;

    @Column(name = "slocation")
    public String sLocation;

    @Column(name = "sclient_acct_id")
    public String sClientAcctId;

    @Column(name = "ninvestigator_id")
    public Integer nInvestigatorId;

    @Column(name = "ninst_id")
    public Integer nInstId;

    @Column(name = "ntemp_account_id")
    public Integer nTempAccountId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ndept_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Department department;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ninvestigator_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Investigator investigator;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "naccount_cpc_mapping_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public AccountCPCMapping accountCPC;

    // Getter and Setter
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<ON> but was:<com.spacestudy.model.Account@783f5f71>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.spacestudy.service.TestAccountService.btnSearchClick(TestAccountService.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
```

**Output from postman**

```
[
    {
        "sAcctDesc": "SRIRAM",
        "sLocation": "ON",
        "sClientAcctId": "1124100",
        "department": {
            "sDeptName": "Deans Office",
            "sClientDeptId": "120010"
        },
        "investigator": {
            "sInvestigatorName": "Ram, Sri"
        },
        "accountCPC": {
            "sCCPCode": "RT"
        }
    }
]
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong in my test case, or suggest an alternative to the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are zero-indexed. That means that if your list has only 1 element, it's index will be 0, not 1.
The element with index 1 is actually the second one (which doesn't exist, thus the index out of bounds).

```
account.get(1)
```

should be

```
account.get(0);
```

Comment: Also, I would strongly consider changing the variable name, "account" does not suggest a collection, rather an Account class object. But that's a different matter..

Comment: I tried I am getting   java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<ON> but was:<com.spacestudy.model.Account@783f5f71>

Comment: Well obviously You are comparing 2 values of different types. One of them (acc.getsLocation()) is a String, and the other (account.get(0)) is an object of different class, they are obviously not equal, so that is the correct behaviour. You may want to add "accounts.get(0).getsLocation()" or otherwise modify your code - I'm not sure what You're trying to achieve

Comment: "accounts.get(0).getsLocation()"  it's working thank  you so much